# Derivatives in Banach Algebra

Tags: analysis, derivatives, banach-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a Banach Algebra. Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval. Let $g,f: I\to \mathcal{A}$ be differentiable function. Then I know that $fg$ is again differentiable with

\begin{equation}
(fg)'=f'g+fg'.
\end{equation}
My first question would be if Leibniz's formula for the nth derivative does also apply in this case?

My second question is whether there is a formula for 
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^k}{d\lambda^k}f^n,
\end{equation}
where $k,n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $f: I\to \mathcal{A}$ is $k$ times differentiable. I found a formula for the real case here:

https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/nth-derivative-of-f-x-n.418767/.

But I can not find a reference.

Comment: Don't you need $A$ to be commutative?

Comment: I don't know. The product rule does apply without a commutative algebra. I overflew the proof of the Leibniz formula and I thought that it also should be true in the case of a Banach algebra. I just wanted to check.